# Create a href url with php variable + javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, url, variables, href

I'm creating links with Mysql+PHP looping, but I need to add a javascript var into url href, like:

The javascript var is in a jquery cookie: `$.cookie('limit')`

**urls.php**:

```
<a href='page.php?id=1&limit=$.cookie('limit')'>1</a>
<a href='page.php?id=2&limit=$.cookie('limit')'>2</a>
<a href='page.php?id=3&limit=$.cookie('limit')'>3</a>
```

Put the javascript var into a hidden input doesn't work on this case.

In my **page.php** I need to use both vars (id and limit) on a mysql query. So insert this javascript var in a hidden input in **page.php** won't work anyway.

I tried to remove limit var from href url and add this on my **page.php** but it didn't work:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['limit']){
    $_REQUEST['limit'] = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write($.cookie('limit'))</script>";
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you clarify?

Comment: How does JavaScript interact with the HREF of your links? Does it create them? Does it read them?

Comment: Right, will try to explain better. Thanks for correction Josh Moore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change links to this:

```
<a href='page.php?id=1' class='changeMe'>1</a>
<a href='page.php?id=2' class='changeMe'>2</a>
<a href='page.php?id=3' class='changeMe'>3</a>
```

Add a javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[class="changeMe"]').each(function(){
        var newHref = $(this).attr("href") +"&limit="+ $.cookie('limit');
        $(this).attr("href", newHref);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not put the variable correctly into php. With your code you just wrote limit inside a string. You need to connect variable to a string like this:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['limit']){
    $limit = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write('".$_REQUEST['limit']."')</script>";
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand how it would work, but I think that was me who made a bad question. Edited my question. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Well, you had some string in $_REQUEST['limit'] variable, and you wanted it in your string (which would client side be executed as JS). In your case JS would be: ...document.write($.cookie('limit'))..., but I told you how to implement the value od the variable into JS (for instance if the value of $_REQUEST['limit'] is 'limit_value' it would be: ...document.write($.cookie('limit_value'))...)

Answer (score 1):

If the limit's being passed into the page that you're constructing links on, then you could grab that number through the $_REQUEST variable like you mentioned.  You could then write a for loop in the logic in that page to create the number of links that you want.  In that loop you could construct something like this to echo the url onto the page:

```
echo "<a href='page.php?id={$i}&limit=jscriptVar'>{$i}</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks Josh Moore for correction. I edited my question to try to explain better what I'm trying to do.